# Terraform - gitlab provider does not start

Tags: terraform, gitlab

I am using terraform docker image `hashicorp/terraform:latest` and I define the provider in main.tf as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "3.3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "gitlab" {
    token = var.gitlab_token
}
```

When I run terraform apply, I get the following error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding gitlabhq/gitlab versions matching "3.3.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/gitlab...
- Installing gitlabhq/gitlab v3.3.0...
- Installed gitlabhq/gitlab v3.3.0 (signed by a HashiCorp partner, key ID BC097C3333027B14)
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.22.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/signing.html
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/gitlab: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/gitlab
If you have just upgraded directly from Terraform v0.12 to Terraform v0.14
then please upgrade to Terraform v0.13 first and follow the upgrade guide for
that release, which might help you address this problem.
Did you intend to use gitlabhq/gitlab? If so, you must specify that source
address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are
currently depending on hashicorp/gitlab, run the following command:
    terraform providers
```

I can't find the solution to this issue from the documentation. Any suggestions?

terraform --version
Terraform v0.14.3

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is one of the providers [not yet included in the Terraform registry](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/#temporary-provider-documentation) - see [this diff](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/commit/cc6a226bcf1c2939587adf6fec0602567a1f5edc#diff-26b540fc4fffb736a64dd49318d9fcb854e78c14db14ca70b31ffc8f67855712) to the documentation. This appears to be a temporary situation:

> The following providers will be published on the Terraform Registry soon, but aren't quite ready. Until they're published, their documentation is available at the links below:

I can't tell from the release notes whether this is only in 0.14.x, but I can confirm that the "old" (*i.e.* current at the time of writing) github provider works with 0.12.x

Comment: I've checked the github repository for the gitlab provider https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab. and the requirement for now is terraform 0.12.x